# ul's display: inline-block is not working and other bugs

Tags: html, css

I have got this html code:

```
<header>
    <a href="index.html">Mira's place</a><br>
    <h2>&#8220;<span id="quote">If nothing, then this.</span>&#8221;</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <li><a href="#">Games</a>
            <li><a href="#">Pixel Art</a>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </ul>
</header>
```

and this CSS

```
::selection {
    background: #D7DD22;
    }
::-moz-selection {
    background: #D7DD22;
}
html {
    background-color: #002240;
    font-family: "Geo", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: #001629;
    margin: 0 -10px 0 -10px;
}
header a:first-child {
    color: #FF628C;
    font-size: 56px;
}
header h2 {
    color: #80FFBB;
}
ul {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
}
p {
    color: white;
}
```

And here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xd7WF/1/ .

I don't get it why but my `display: inline-block` is not working on my `ul`. It's not next to each other as it's supossed to be. Also my `first-child` is not working. It affects other `a`'s. Can anyone help me?

Comment: While HTML5 doesn't **require** you to do so, you really should be closing your list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use display `inline-block;` on the `<li>` elements instead

http://jsfiddle.net/Xd7WF/2/

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, but what about that first-child?

Comment: That's weird. It's not working for me even I change my browser.

Comment: The first-child is the text "Mira's place" and it is adhering to the styling declared to the first parent without any problems. Do you mean first-child of the list?

Comment: I will create another question for it with better explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want the `<li>` elements inline, not the `<ul>`. Therefore you set that value to the `<li>` elements.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```